# Invoke base event handler in C# 6

Tags: c#, event-handling

I have a simple abstract class:

```csharp
abstract class Lesson
{
    public event EventHandler<SpeakEventArgs> Speak;
    public string OpeningMessage { get; set; }
    public string ClosingMessage { get; set; }
    public bool completed { get; private set; } = false;
    abstract public void Do();
}
```

And a simple sub-class:

```csharp
class BubbleSort : Lesson
{
    public override void Do()
    {
        base.Speak?.Invoke(this, new SpeakEventArgs { Message = OpeningMessage });
    }
}
```

The sub-class uses the C# 6 null-conditional operator `?.`. This code gives the error

> The event 'Lesson.Speak' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -= (except when used within the type 'Lesson')

Surely as a sub-class I am here within the type 'Lesson'? How do I do this invocation of the base class event within the sub-class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't Invoke an event in any class other than the one that it was declared in

instead i would suggest creating a raise method in your base class that performs the required checks then raises the event for you

```
protected void raiseSpeak(SpeakEventArgs args)
{
    this.Speak?.Invoke(sender, args);
}
```

or in your case just remove the abstract from do and raise the event in the do method in your lesson class, which you can then override for extra functionality

```
abstract class Lesson
{
    public event EventHandler<SpeakEventArgs> Speak;

    public virtual void Do()
    {
        this.Speak?.Invoke(sender, args);
    }
}

class BubbleSort : Lesson
{
    public override void Do()
    {
        base.Do();
        //do something BubbleSort related
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You *cannot* directly invoke an event from outside the class that defines it, even from a sub-class.

Solution: use a `protected` method to fire it:

```
internal abstract class Lesson
{
    public event EventHandler<SpeakEventArgs> Speak;

    public string OpeningMessage { get; set; }
    public string ClosingMessage { get; set; }
    public bool completed { get; private set; } = false;

    abstract public void Do();

    protected void DoSpeak(SpeakEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.Speak != null)
        {
            this.Speak(this, e);
        }
    }
}

internal class BubbleSort : Lesson
{
    public override void Do()
    {
        base.DoSpeak(new SpeakEventArgs { Message = OpeningMessage });
    }
}
```

Comment: `this.Speak(this, e);` is not thread safe, it is possible for something to unsubscribe from the event between the null check and the call, instead you should copy the handlers to a object then check that for null and call from there

Comment: @MIkeT which gets you absolutely nothing; you are simply changing the race condition, not removing it. Now you have an event firing when it shouldn't be.

Comment: @MikeT Yes it's not thread safe, but it doesn't pretend to be. What you suggest is not either. It's actually a common mistake, you shouldn't do that . See http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/06/threadsafe-events.html

Comment: thats a very interesting article, however i will add that i have (admittedly very rarely) hit the problem of this code throwing a null reference exception, where as i've never had an issue with the MS recommended method, though thats probably the difference in getting hit by a breaking but not harmful exception and running potentially harmful code because its out of date

Comment: @MikeT Sometimes it's far better to have a code that crashes throwing an exception, than a code that silently runs but doesn't accomplish the expected tasks. What if the event handler that shouldn't have been called is responsible to drop a database? The general consensus is that the event model is fundamentally _not_ thread-safe. If you actually have multiple threads that register/unregister event handlers, then design something better that _actually_ work in multi-threading environments (not something that work 95% of times).

Comment: @ken2k i thought that's what i said;)

Comment: i guess the only 100% correct way is yours with the addition of a try catch to clean up the occasional mishap

Answer (score 0):

[You will have to provide a raise method in your abstract class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hy3sefw3.aspx), eg:

```
abstract class Lesson
{
    public event EventHandler<SpeakEventArgs> Speak;
    public string OpeningMessage { get; set; }
    public string ClosingMessage { get; set; }
    public bool completed { get; private set; } = false;
    abstract public void Do();

    protected virtual void RaiseSpeak(object sender, SpeakEventArgs args)
    {
        this.Speak?.Invoke(sender, args);
    }
}
```

which you then can override optionally, eg:

```
class BubbleSort : Lesson
{
    protected override void RaiseSpeak(object sender, SpeakEventArgs args)
    {
        // your logic here

        base.RaiseSpeak(sender, args);
    }

    public override void Do()
    {
        this.RaiseSpeak(this, new SpeakEventArgs() { Message = OpeningMessage });
    }
}
```